# Storing Javascript Map across node clusters

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I currently save references to sockets in a Javascript Map. I need to make this map accessible to instances of node running on all clusters, so that I can always get the `socket.id` associated with a user. In my app module:

```
var socketMap = new Map()

// socket.io events
io.on( "connection", function( socket )
{
  if (socket.request.session.authenticated_user) {
    console.log( "A user connected" );
    socketMap.set(socket.request.session.authenticated_user.toString(), socket.id);

    socket.on( "disconnect", function() {
      console.log( "A user disconnected" );
      socketMap.delete(socket.request.session.authenticated_user);
    });
  }
});

var emit_to_socket = function (user_id, message) {

  if (socketMap.has(user_id.toString())) {
    if (socketMap.get(user_id.toString())) {
      io.to(socketMap.get(user_id.toString())).emit('message', message);
    }
  }
};

exports.emit_to_socket = emit_to_socket;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to make this map accessible to instances of node running on all clusters, so that I can always get the socket.id associated with a user.

If you need to share data with all clusters, you can't use a Javascript in-memory object such as a `Map` object.  Instead, you will need to use something that can be shared across multiple processes (your cluster processes).  A common solution for something like this is to use Redis (in memory database) that all clustered processes can then access.  Redis has capabilities that will let you do something similar to your Map object.

In fact, the clustered version of socket.io already uses redis for this purpose so it can keep track of all the rooms and all connected users across all clusters and any cluster can broadcast to any room or send to any socket regardless of which cluster they are connected to.

Alternatively, you could have your main process keep the Map object and then every other one in the cluster would have to communicate with the main cluster via interprocess communication to get or set something from the single Map object (essentially a poor man's Redis for a single purpose).